# TAR or ZIP current directory excluding the generated file

Tags: linux, zip, tar, exclude

I am trying to zip or tar all the files and subdirectories in current directory and save it to the file I am zipping. The problem is that -x shitch does not work - files are being zipped and saved to a random-named file.

```
zip -r backup.zip ./* -x backup.zip
```

This is what I tried but the code did not work properly.

Is there any way to do this without saving the archive .. directory and then moving it back to the ./ dir?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zip will not attempt to zip it's own out file so you don't need to use -x. Assuming backup.zip already exists in the current directory and we try to update the zip:

```
# zip -r backup.zip ./*
updating: libproxychains4.so (deflated 61%)
updating: README (deflated 55%)
updating: TODO (deflated 17%)
updating: COPYING (deflated 62%)
updating: src/ (stored 0%)
updating: src/proxychains (deflated 65%)
updating: src/core.c (deflated 70%)
updating: src/common.o (deflated 68%)
updating: src/core.o (deflated 66%)
updating: src/main.c (deflated 58%)
updating: src/core.h (deflated 66%)
updating: src/libproxychains.c (deflated 69%)
updating: src/proxyresolv (deflated 30%)
updating: src/main.o (deflated 67%)
updating: src/libproxychains.o (deflated 70%)
updating: src/common.h (deflated 55%)
updating: src/proxychains.conf (deflated 57%)
updating: src/common.c (deflated 62%)
updating: proxychains.lsm (deflated 28%)
updating: configure (deflated 65%)
updating: AUTHORS (deflated 45%)
updating: dist/ (stored 0%)
updating: dist/config.mak (deflated 43%)
updating: ChangeLog (deflated 66%)
updating: config.mak (deflated 37%)
updating: proxychains4 (deflated 62%)
updating: tests/ (stored 0%)
updating: tests/test_getaddrinfo.c (deflated 51%)
updating: Makefile (deflated 58%)
```

Use -x if you really need to exclude a file from your backup.

Answer (score 0):

`./*` is expanded by the shell *before* being sent to the command, so the only way `zip` will try to include `backup.zip` is if it exists *before* running the command.

`tar` can do it:

```
$ cd -- "$(mktemp -d)" 
$ touch -- $'--$`!*@\a\b\E\f\r\t\v\\\'"\360\240\202\211 \n'
$ tar -czf test.tar.gz ./*
$ ls
--$`!*@???????\'" ?  test.tar.gz
$ tar -tvf test.tar.gz 
-rw-rw-r-- user/group      0 2013-06-26 14:38 ./--$`!*@\a\b\033\f\r\t\v\\'" \n
```